# Eurosign gives strange result

Tags: excel, powershell, number-formatting, euro

I've a problem when I'm assigning currency format to a specific range in a Excel sheet.
The code in powershell I use to set the format is below :

```
$LC_ws_tab.range("B1 :B5").NumberFormat = "_(€* #.##0,00_);_(€* (#.##0,00);_(€* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
```

The thing i find strange is that - iff I run the code I see the screenshot below (euro sign = â,-) .

[image]

But when I run the code a second time via "run selected code" when excel document is still open there is a euro sign.
Does anyone know why I've this result?

The complete sample code u see below:

```
function Excel_new {
    $object = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
    $object | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name FullQuit -Value {Excel_FullQuit}
    $object
}


function Excel_FullQuit {
    while ( $this.Workbooks.Count -gt 0 ) {
        $this.Workbooks.Item(1).Close()
    }
    $this.Quit()
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($this)
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    Stop-Process -processname EXCEL
}


$Excel = Excel_new
$Excel.Visible = $true
$Excel.displayalerts = $false 


$path  = "C:\somefolder\test.xlsx"
$LC_wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($path)
$LC_ws_tab = $LC_wb.Worksheets.Add()
$LC_ws_tab.name = "test"
# $LC_ws_tab.range("A1 :A5").NumberFormat = "#.##0,00  € "
# $LC_ws_tab.range("B1 :B5").NumberFormat = "€ #.##0,00"
# $LC_ws_tab.range("C1 :C5").NumberFormat = "0,00 % "
$LC_ws_tab.Cells.Item( 1 , 1 ) = 49999
$LC_ws_tab.Cells.Item( 1 , 2 ) = 1234.879
$LC_ws_tab.Cells.Item( 1 , 3 ) = 1234.879
$LC_ws_tab.range("B1 :B5").NumberFormat = "_(€* #.##0,00_);_(€* (#.##0,00);_(€* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, although I did not use your function `Excel_new` because it tries to add a scriptmethod to the COM object using an undefined function `Excel_FullQuit`. Are you closing the workbook (`$LC_wb.Close($true)` ? and quitting Excel after that **and Release the COMObjects** ?

Comment: @Theo I've added the full_quit function  ;)